# Accessing variables from another ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
    {
    NSArray *listData;
}
-(IBAction) GoToInsert: (id) sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData;
@end
```

---

FirstViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction) upisiRezultat:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    [self presentModalViewController: secondView animated: NO];
    [secondView release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"236", @"46",
                   @"147", @"8", @"56", @"69", @"114", @"2",
                   @"96", @"518", @"2", @"54", @"236", nil];
    self.listData = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

---

SecondViewontroller.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {

}
-(IBAction) insert;
@end
```

---

SecondViewontroller.m

```
-(IBAction) insert
{
    /* Here should be the code to insert some number in listData from FirstViewController */
}
```

So when the app loads it loads FirstViewController.xib and shows the listData array on screen, when I click button "Go to Insert" another view is loaded (SecondViewController.xib) with button "Insert" which should add some number into the array and display the new array on the first view.

How to do that?

Comment: more readable code:
http://pastebin.com/GBk1V7ac

Comment: You can format the code on Stack Overflow my clicking the `{}` when writing the question.

Comment: @Wikiboo: Let me know if that code helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent view controller with `self.parentViewController`. Therefore something along these lines (meaning I haven't tested this -- you should) should work:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = self.parentViewController;
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:firstViewControl.listData];
[newArray addObject:@"42"];
[firstViewController setListData:[NSArray arrayWithArray:newArray]];
[newArray release];
```

However, since you want to add objects to `listArray`, it would be more natural to use an `NSMutableArray` instead. Also, you are currently adding `NSString`s to the array, when it looks more like you want to have `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: Should I have an instances of FirstViewController and SecondViewController in AppDelegate.h?

Comment: I have no idea. I cannot see your AppDelegate.h file and I do not know how your app is organized. The code above is what I propose for your `-(IBAction) insert` method in SecondViewController.m.

Comment: I will try and let you know if it works :)

Another question, what is the best way to share variables between view controllers?

Comment: @Wikiboo It depends on what the variable is and what you want to do with it. I'm a fan of `NSUserDefaults` for `int`s and `NSString`s.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have `imported` the SecondViewController.h , and I think I have an idea an what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, this helps very much! :)
Is this the usual way of transferring values beetwen view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, and maybe easier, you could have the variables in your main AppDelegate.

Put:
   int myNumber;
in the projectname_AppDelegate.h file

Then in each of your view controllers, you can import your AppDelegate.h file and then do something like:

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
and then read or change:

appDelegate.myNumber

===

This is not something you should be doing all the time (you don't want your appDelegate to be a giant data repository) but it could give you a quick fix when needed...

Comment: Should I in every method in other view controllers declare
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myNumb
if I want to use that variable in those methods?

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is the best way to share variables between view controllers...

Comment: In your FirstViewController.h, import the app delegate and have the variable AppDelegate *appDelegate;  Then, in viewdidload, say appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  ...Then, wherever you need it, just refer to appDelegate.myNumber